# Read data from app.properties gluon build issue

Tags: maven, javafx, gluon

I have a problem using the Gluon FX plugin with a JavaFX application. I need to build an executable `.exe` file. I have `app.properties` in my project, but the final application looks like the configuration from the `app.properties` are not present; `app.properties` file is located at the root of the project.

I build my sources with `mvn gluonfx:build`. I have tried `mvn gluonfx:runagent` before `mvn gluonfx:build`, but the result is same.

How to add configuration to my app? Are there other ways to set configuration variables and build `.exe`? If you need more information to help, just let me know.

P.S: This is my first post on StackOverflow. Please excuse me for any mistake I have made in posting the question.

Comment: See https://docs.gluonhq.com/#_configuration. You can use `<resourcesList><item>app.properties</item></resourcesList>` in your pom. Anyway, `runAgent` should have discovered that resource (check `src/main/resources/META-INF/native-image/resource-config.json`)

Comment: @JoséPereda I added `<item>app.properties</item>` just you suggested, but the result has no changes. Unfortunately, `runAgent` creates `resource-config.json` with no information about my `app.properties`

Comment: The latter means the agent is not discovering the use of such properties file. When you run `gluonfx:runagent`, make sure you explore your application so it discovers all possible scenarios. Also, make sure it works fine with `gluonfx:run` in the first place.